Explanation for the secretary problem solution
In deriving the optimal policy for the secretary problem, there is one line that goes from
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}
P\left(\text{applicant } i \text{ is selected} | \text{applicant } i \text{ is the best}\right) \cdot
P\left(\text{applicant } i \text{ is the best}\right)$$
to
$$\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{r-1} 0
+ \sum_{i=r}^{n} P\left( \left.
\begin{array}{l}
\text{the best of the first } i - 1 \text{ applicants} \\
\text{is in the first } r-1 \text{ applicants}
\end{array} \right|  \text{applicant } i \text{ is the best}
\right) \right] \cdot \frac{1}{n}$$
I don't understand the conditional probability here. If it is given that applicant $i$ is the best, then under what conditions do we reject them?

If you use the first $r-1$ candidates for standard setting, then there are two reasons you might not select the best candidate $i$:

you see the best candidate too early before you are ready to start selecting;
or perhaps you see a candidate better than all the first $r-1$ candidates but worse than $i$ before you see $i$.

The first of these gives you $0$ conditional probability of selecting $i$ when $1 \le i \le r-1$,
while the second a conditional probability of selecting $i$ equal to the conditional probability that the best of the first $i-1$ candidates is among the first $r-1$ when $r \le i \le n$,
and, together with the uniform distribution of $i$, this produces the second expression in your question.

As an illustration, suppose you had $4$ candidates and decided to set $r=3$. We will call their rankings $A,B,C,D$ from best to worst in some permutation, so there are $4!=24$ equally likely permutations. $10$ of these lead to the correct choice of candidate so a probability of $\frac{10}{24}=\frac5{12}$:

If $i=1$, i.e. the first candidate is $A$ with probability $\frac{6}{24}=\frac14$ since this covers $ABCD$, $ABDC$, $ACBD$, $ACDB$, $ADBC$, $ADCB$, then the conditional probability of choosing that candidate is $0$ since  $i < r$ and you cannot choose an early candidate

If $i=2$, i.e. the second candidate is $A$ with probability $\frac{6}{24}=\frac14$ since this covers $BACD$, $BADC$, $CABD$, $CADB$, $DABC$, $DACB$, then the conditional probability of choosing that candidate is $0$ since  $i < r$ and you cannot choose an early candidate

If $i=3$, i.e. the third candidate is $A$ with probability $\frac{6}{24}=\frac14$ since this covers $BCAD$, $BDAC$, $CBAD$, $CDAB$, $DBAC$, $DCAB$, then the conditional probability of choosing that candidate is $1=\frac{i-1}{r-1}$ since you will correctly choose the third as being better than the first two (trivially when the best of the first two candidates is the best of the first two candidates)

If $i=4$, i.e. the fourth candidate is $A$ with probability $\frac{6}{24}=\frac14$ since this covers $BCDA$, $BDCA$, $CBDA$, $CDBA$, $DBCA$, $DCBA$, then the conditional probability of choosing that candidate is $\frac46=\frac23=\frac{i-1}{r-1}$ since you will incorrectly choose the third as being better than the first two with $CDBA$ or $DCBA$ (when the best of the first three candidates is not the best of the first two candidates), but will correctly not choose the third and instead choose the fourth as being better than the first two with $BCDA$, $BDCA$, $CBDA$, $DBCA$ (when the best of the first three candidates is the best of the first two candidates)


Combining these conditional probabilities would give a probability of making the right choice of $$\frac14\times 0 +\frac14\times 0+\frac14\times 1+\frac14\times \frac23 =\frac5{12}.$$

"or perhaps you see a candidate better than all the first $r-1$ candidates but worse than $i$ before you see $i$."
But at this point we are looking to reject or accept the $i$-th candidate.

@trivialmathisdifficult You want to accept the $i$th candidate as that is the best candidate, but you can only do so if (a) you have not rejected the $i$th candidate and (b) you have not previously accepted another candidate.  Both of those depend on the value of $i$ and the second also depends on the relative rankings of the other candidates.  These conditional probabilities are not about your decision when seeing the $i$th candidate but whether you see the $i$ candidate at the right time, given the value of $i$.

I guess I don't understand this part: "while the second a conditional probability of selecting $i$ equal to the conditional probability that the best of the first $i-1$ candidates is among the first $r-1$ when $r \le i \le n$,"

@trivialmathisdifficult I have added an illustration to my answer
